# jQuery :last-child selector

Tags: jquery

How do I add class="x" to the last table cell that's on the same row as the one that has class="insert"?
Something like:

```
$('td.insert').parents('tr').(':last-child').addClass('x');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('td.insert').siblings(':last-child').addClass('x');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like this:

```
$('td.insert').siblings(':last-child').addClass('x');
```

This filters the sibling cells, leaving only the last child to add the class to.

Comment: Nick, I'm going to give it to the little guy.